# WPF Keep Button Position When Layout Changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button layed out on my WPF form with the following XAML:

```
 <Button Name="CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton" Content="Check for Third Party Updates" Click="checkForThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="195" Height="25" MaxHeight="29" Margin="17,19,445,26"/>
```

The layout of the WPF before the button is clicked is the following:

[image]

The problem is once the "Check for Third Party Updates" button is clicked, the height of the window increases by about 500 pixels. So because of the margin I have set on the button, it sinks to the button of the window and is covered up by a newly visible listbox (generated by the button click). How can I force the button to hold its position?

Comment: Its Better to avoid Margin, Use some Grid Definitions to place the Button.

Comment: Can you more of XAML code as it depends on in which control you are lying this button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your Button position using `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment`

```
 <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton" Content="Check for Third Party Updates" Click="checkForThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="195" Height="25" MaxHeight="29" Margin="17,19,445,26"/>
```